# How to get an xtype's value in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Let's suppose i have the following piece of code:

```
{
xtype : 'textfield',
xxxx : 'firstname',
//I just need a method to return xxxx's value(which is firstname)
yyyy : this.hypothetical_get_xxxx_value()}
                            }
```

It might seem useless but I need to get some config object's value. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but one way to get access to xxxx is by adding `itemId: 'myTextFieldName',` to your textField object so that it can be referenced. Then make a call on the containing component (e.g. a FormPanel) to obtain that textField object's xxxx property:

`var value = containingComponent.getComponent('myTextFieldName').xxxx`

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

If you have id attribute for textfield, you can get any attribute value,
Eg:

```
   {
      xtype : 'textfield',
      xxxx : 'firstname',
      yyyy : this.hypothetical_get_xxxx_value()}
      id   : 'somename'
   }

   var xxxxValue = Ext.getCmp('somename').xxxx;  
  // it will give you xxxx's value...
```